# PL/SQL compilations error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Orden (n1 IN number, n2 IN number, n3 IN number) AS

    menor number;
        mediano number;
        mayor number;
    BEGIN
        IF (n1<n2) THEN 
            IF (n1<n3) THEN 
                menor := n1;
                IF (n2<n3) THEN
                    mediano := n2;
                    mayor := n3;
                ELSE 
                    mediano := n3;
                    mayor := n2;
                END IF;
            ELSE 
                menor := n3;
                mediano :=n1;
                mayor := n2;
            END IF;
        ELSE 
            IF (n1 < n3) THEN 
                menor := n2;
                mediano := n1;
                mayor := n3;
            ELSE 
                mayor := n1;
                IF(n2< n3) THEN 
                    medio := n2;
                    menor := n3;
                ELSE 
                    medio := n3;
                    menor := n2;
                END IF;
        END IF;
        n1 := menor;
        n2 := medio;
        n3 := mayor;                
    END;
/
```

The error is the next:

> 39/5     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of
>   the
>        following:
>        if

Comment: You've indented your code, which is good; but that doesn't help you spot the missing `END IF;` ?

Comment: Don't edit the question to remove the problem you were having - it invalidates the existing answer. If you have a new problem ask a new question. But Aleksej's answer already preempted the PLS-00363 you are now getting - look at the third bullet point.

Comment: I found  the missing [END IF] , but now give me an error. However i could resolve turning inside out the variables n1,n2,n3 by menor , mediano , mayor and viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

Three issues:

- you are missing an `END IF`
- `medio` is never declared; maybe you mean `mediano`?
- if you want to assing a value to your input parameters, they need to be `IN OUT`.

An hint: `CASE` could be a more readable way to implement the same logic.

Comment: Thank you very much, but now i have another problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "another problem"? With the edit I suggested, the procedure should compile.What is the problem?